# Apache Pulsar unable to validate issuer certificate when attempting to load OpenID Connect provider

Tags: apache-pulsar

I've attempted to follow the instructions on https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.0.x/security-openid-connect/ in order to enable OpenID Connect Authentication, but can't seem to get passed a certificate error.

I believe this error stems from pulsar's [AuthenticationProviderOpenID.java](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/master/pulsar-broker-auth-oidc/src/main/java/org/apache/pulsar/broker/authentication/oidc/AuthenticationProviderOpenID.java) class, where in the initialise method it attempts to setup the SSL context to enable a secure connection to the issuer url provided.

In the example [broker.conf](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.0.x/security-openid-connect/) it says that the "openIDTokenIssuerTrustCertsFilePath" is an optional setting and that it will use the trust store of the JVM. So I ensured that the required certificates where added to the trust store found at ".../jre/lib/security/cacerts" on my broker instance and left that config value as blank. This did not work, I was presented with the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid certificates:
....
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: could not find certificate file:
at io.netty.handler.ssl.PemReader.readCertificates(PemReader.java:68) ~[io.netty-netty-handler-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
```

This to me seemed to indicate that it was expecting a .pem file to be supplied, so I copied the pem file onto the broker server and supplied the absolute path to the file as `openIDTokenIssuerTrustCertsFilePath=/opt/pulsar/certificates/certificate.pem`

but I received the error

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: found no certificates in input stream
```

Here is a example of the broker.conf settings I'm using.

**broker.conf settings**
authenticationProviders=org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.oidc.AuthenticationProviderOpenID

```
openIDAllowedTokenIssuers=https://login-stg.somewebsite.com/
openIDAllowedAudiences=https://auth0-some-website.com/maas, https://some-stg.some-dev.auth0.com/userinfo
        
openIDTokenIssuerTrustCertsFilePath=
openIDRoleClaim=https://some-web.com/role
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the example broker.conf it says that the
> "openIDTokenIssuerTrustCertsFilePath" is an optional setting and that
> it will use the trust store of the JVM. So I ensured that the required
> certificates where added to the trust store found at
> ".../jre/lib/security/cacerts" on my broker instance and left that
> config value as blank.

It will work correctly when you remove the `openIDTokenIssuerTrustCertsFilePath=` from your `broker.conf` file. Having a blank `openIDTokenIssuerTrustCertsFilePath=` is incorrectly configuring the provider to attempt to load the `""` file, which explains the unhelpful error message.

Note: https://github.com/apache/pulsar/pull/20745 should improve the behavior in a future release of pulsar by interpreting an empty configuration as using the OS's trust store.

> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: found no certificates in input stream

In my testing, I observed this same error when the file was not in PEM format. I verified that the feature does work for custom trust stores configured using correctly formated files with these modified tests: https://github.com/apache/pulsar/pull/20746.

Here is my full stack trace for the incorrectly formatted ca cert:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid certificates: /Users/michaelmarshall/dev/apache/pulsar/pulsar-broker-auth-oidc/target/test-classes/certificate-authority/jks/broker.keystore.jks

    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.trustManager(SslContextBuilder.java:261)
    at org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.oidc.AuthenticationProviderOpenID.initialize(AuthenticationProviderOpenID.java:172)
    at org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.oidc.AuthenticationProviderOpenIDIntegrationTest.testKidCacheMissWhenRefreshConfigZero(AuthenticationProviderOpenIDIntegrationTest.java:347)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:677)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:969)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:829)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:431)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:391)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: found no certificates in input stream
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.PemReader.readCertificates(PemReader.java:107)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.PemReader.readCertificates(PemReader.java:63)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.toX509Certificates(SslContext.java:1219)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.trustManager(SslContextBuilder.java:259)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Thank you, removing the line as you suggested seems to of resolved this issue. But I'm immediately faced with another related to the functions_worker.yml config which I've described in this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633061/apache-pulsar-fails-to-enable-openid-authentication-in-function-worker-when-conf, would appreciate your help here if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your questions @raah! I submitted an answer there too. Your question also led to this documentation fix: https://github.com/apache/pulsar-site/pull/632