# Apache Pulsar fails to enable OpenID authentication in function worker when configured as specified in documentation

Tags: apache-pulsar

When following the [documentation](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.0.x/security-openid-connect/#enable-openid-connect-authentication-in-the-function-worker) on enabling OpenID Connect authentication in the Function Worker, you are presented with the following error.

```
[jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd] error Uncaught exception in thread main: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.HashSet` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.oidc.AuthenticationProviderOpenID')
```

I'm not sure what value if any I've configured incorrectly to cause this, here is an example of my configuration in the functions_worker.yml file.

```
authenticationEnabled: true
authenticationProviders: "org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.oidc.AuthenticationProviderOpenID"
properties:
  openIDAllowedTokenIssuers: "https://stg.some-website.com/"
  openIDAllowedAudiences: "https://some-website.com/maas, https://some-website.com/userinfo"
  openIDRoleClaim: "https://some-web.com/role"
  openIDAcceptedTimeLeewaySeconds: 0
  openIDCacheSize: 5
  openIDCacheRefreshAfterWriteSeconds: 64800
  openIDCacheExpirationSeconds: 86400
  openIDHttpConnectionTimeoutMillis: 10000
  openIDHttpReadTimeoutMillis: 10000
  openIDRequireIssuersUseHttps: true
  openIDFallbackDiscoveryMode: "DISABLED"
```

Here is the full stack trace

```
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: 2023-07-06T22:47:15,473Z [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd] error Uncaught exception in thread main: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.HashSet` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.oidc.AuthenticationProviderOpenID')
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at [Source: (File); line: 306, column: 26] (through reference chain: org.apache.pulsar.functions.worker.WorkerConfig["authenticationProviders"]) 
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.HashSet` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.oidc.AuthenticationProviderOpenID')
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at [Source: (File); line: 306, column: 26] (through reference chain: org.apache.pulsar.functions.worker.WorkerConfig["authenticationProviders"]) 
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1728)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1353)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromString(StdDeserializer.java:311)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringCollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(StringCollectionDeserializer.java:284)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringCollectionDeserializer.deserialize(StringCollectionDeserializer.java:192)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringCollectionDeserializer.deserialize(StringCollectionDeserializer.java:182)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringCollectionDeserializer.deserialize(StringCollectionDeserializer.java:25)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3494)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at org.apache.pulsar.functions.worker.WorkerConfig.load(WorkerConfig.java:776)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at org.apache.pulsar.broker.PulsarService.initializeWorkerConfigFromBrokerConfig(PulsarService.java:1840)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at org.apache.pulsar.PulsarBrokerStarter$BrokerStarter.<init>(PulsarBrokerStarter.java:194)
Jul 06 22:47:15 lin-0afa7c99.mstarext.com pulsar[6665]: at org.apache.pulsar.PulsarBrokerStarter.main(PulsarBrokerStarter.java:333)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authenticationProviders` parameter must be passed as a yaml list. Here is the correct input:

```
authenticationProviders: ["org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.oidc.AuthenticationProviderOpenID"]
```

You can also input it this way:

```
authenticationProviders:
  - "org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.oidc.AuthenticationProviderOpenID"
```

Note that the error indicates this when it says:

> Cannot construct instance of `java.util.HashSet`

It is trying to create a set from the value of `authenticationProviders`.

Note: the docs were originally incorrect. I updated them here: https://github.com/apache/pulsar-site/pull/632.

Comment: Perfect thank you, you're a star! I appreciate your help and the documentation fixes. The broker service is now failing to start because of a 401 unauthorised error, but I'm going to try spend some time fixing/debugging it before asking for help. I have a hunch it might be because I'm restarting a broker service on a cluster that already had some functions/processes configured to run on it (like the kafka connector etc). So am going to start with a freshly deployed cluster

Comment: Posted the issue I'm facing here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76636436/why-does-apache-pulsar-fails-to-start-the-broker-service-when-enabling-openid-co