# Why does Apache Pulsar fails to start the broker service when enabling OpenID Connect Authentication?

Tags: apache-pulsar

After following the [documentation](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.0.x/security-openid-connect/) (and answers in SO questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76631732/apache-pulsar-unable-to-validate-issuer-certificate-when-attempting-to-load-open) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633061/apache-pulsar-fails-to-enable-openid-authentication-in-function-worker-when-conf)) to enable OpenID Connection Authentication the pulsar.broker service fails to start and provides me with a flurry of 401 not authorised errors. I was not expecting this as I thought authentication/authorisation was only initiated from a pulsar client where an access token can be supplied.

Here are an example of some of the 401 errors presented to me:

```
lin-0afa7c37.mstarext.com pulsar[12971]: 2023-07-07T10:19:33,590+0000 [main] ERROR org.apache.pulsar.functions.worker.PulsarWorkerService - Error Starting up in worker
lin-0afa7c37.mstarext.com pulsar[12971]: org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.PulsarAdminException$NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
....
lin-0afa7c37.mstarext.com pulsar[12971]: Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
....
lin-0afa7c37.mstarext.com pulsar[12971]: 2023-07-07T10:19:33,597+0000 [main] ERROR org.apache.pulsar.broker.PulsarService - Failed to start Pulsar service: org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.PulsarAdminException$NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
....
lin-0afa7c37.mstarext.com pulsar[12971]: 2023-07-07T10:19:33,598+0000 [main] ERROR org.apache.pulsar.PulsarBrokerStarter - Failed to start pulsar service.
lin-0afa7c37.mstarext.com pulsar[12971]: org.apache.pulsar.broker.PulsarServerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.PulsarAdminException$NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
```

Is there some other configuration that I need to update that's not mentioned in the referenced documentation above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When authentication is enabled, the Pulsar Broker, Proxy, and Function Worker must be configured to use authentication. Since OIDC is an OAuth2 implementation, you can follow the OAuth2 docs here: https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.0.x/security-oauth2/#enable-oauth2-authentication-on-brokersproxies.

The broker.conf will look something like this (it varies based on your OAuth2 provider):

```
brokerClientAuthenticationPlugin=org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.auth.oauth2.AuthenticationOAuth2
# When client credentials are stored in a file
brokerClientAuthenticationParameters={"privateKey":"file:///path/to/privateKey","audience":"https://dev-kt-aa9ne.us.auth0.com/api/v2/","issuerUrl":"https://dev-kt-aa9ne.us.auth0.com"}

# When client credentials are stored in a base64 string
brokerClientAuthenticationParameters={"privateKey":"data:application/json;base64,privateKey-body-to-base64","audience":"https://dev-kt-aa9ne.us.auth0.com/api/v2/","issuerUrl":"https://dev-kt-aa9ne.us.auth0.com"}

# If using secret key (Note: key files must be DER-encoded)
tokenSecretKey=file:///path/to/secret.key
```

Note also that if you are running in Kubernetes, it is possible to mount a service account token projection and use that token for authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the response michael, understood. Even after configuring the broker.conf as suggested I still get an error.

Comment: The error I received was an access denied error. Even though I supplied what I thought was the correct client credentials in a json file. 

Error:
client.api.PulsarClientException$AuthenticationException: Unable to obtain an access token: Unauthorized (access_denied)

privatekey.json file: 
{"type": "client_credentials", "client_id": "mockid@company.com", "client_secret": "sasdiQM....asds", "issuer_url": "https://someurl.com/"} 

I've tested my client credentials via postmans and can retrieve an access token. The only difference being an access token url is provided (.../token/oauth)

Comment: I believe my issue is actually related to the token endpoint url being presented in the "https://login.someweb.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" documentation. Annoyingly this will take a while to update to the correct url. Is there anyway in Pulsar that I can override this with the correct url?

Comment: @raah - what is the issue with the URL? The `.well-known/openid-configuration` is added to the `issuer_url` to retrieve the token authorization endpoint, which is part of the OIDC spec (and possibly the OAuth2 spec).

Comment: apologies for the delayed response. The issue was the token url presented in the openid-configuration was not the url I was expecting/what it should have been.